# Flattening MultiIndex pivot table in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Here's my pivot table column structure (multiindex):

```
      col2  col3  col4  sales

month                   month_1  month_2  month_3
```

I would like to flatten it to:

```
      col2  col3  col4  month_1  month_2  month_3
```

If I do `pivot.columns = pivot.columns.get_level_values(0)`, then the result is:

```
      col2  col3  col4  sales  sales  sales
```

What do I do?

Comment: What is your code of pivot?

Comment: Hi @jezrael! There it is: pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,
                             index=['col2', 'col3', 'col4'],
                             columns=['month'],
                             values=['sales'],
                             aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think solution is remove `[]` around `[sales]` and `[months]` if pivoting only by one column `sales`.

So code is:

```
 pivot = (pd.pivot_table(df, 
                         index=['col2','col3','col4'],
                         columns='month', 
                         values='sales')
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Comment: Omg... of course, you're right. Had no idea that these brackets would make such a difference here. Thanks a ton, man! Super fast help, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @jezrael : Super helpful! Such small things that we can miss at times.. removing [] solved the issues!

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this, where "pivot" is the name of your pivot table:

```
pivot_flat = pd.DataFrame(pivot.to_records())
```

This will flatten your pivot table so you can perform more robust visualizations or add in other calculated columns and transformations. Essentially, you'll go from this:

[image: pivot table]

To this:

[image: flat pivot table]

Comment: to_records() will convert to "NumPy ndarray with the DataFrame labels as fields and each row of the DataFrame as entries" as of [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html)

Comment: yes, but if you chain it with pd.DataFrame(df.to_records()), it comes back out as a dataframe resembling a SQL query result table. I've used this in production code multiple times to get a resultant dataframe without issue. About the only thing you might have to do is convert a column's datatype due to pandas inference.